# Eclipse: multiple monitors / positioning of dialogs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to setup Eclipse for two monitors (a 1600x1200). I have one big desktop spanning over both monitors. Eclipse places some dialogs (CTRL+3) exactly centered on my desktop, this means that one half of the dialog is on the left monitor, the other one on the right one.

When I move the dialog, close it, and open it again, the last position isn't remembered by Eclipse. Any way around this issue? Or is there a plugin, which helps to open all dialogs not centered, but placed with an offset to the left / right?

Thanks.

Comment: Argh. Finally found the simple solution: In the upper right corner is a small triangle, which opens a a context menu, with the desired entry "remember position".

Comment: @user168954: excellent! I have included your solution in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what exact dialogs you are talking about.

Dialogs can remember their last position since Eclipse3.2: [bug 111530](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=111530) and [bug 33550](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=33550).
Different dialogs now remember their positions: [bug 108801](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108801):

- [Bug #111650 - JDT dialogs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=111650)
- [Bug #111652 - Search dialog](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=111652)
- [Bug #111653 - Text dialogs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=111653)

If other dialogs don't work correctly, a new bug report is in order.

---

Regarding the "**Quick Access**" (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>) dialog the OP is actually referring to, he comments:

> Finally found the simple solution:
>   **In the upper right corner is a small triangle, which opens a a context menu, with the desired entry "remember position"**.

Comment: I'm talking about the "Quick Access" (CTRL+3) dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Read this question:
[Any tips on how to organize Eclipse environment on multiple monitors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318940/any-tips-on-how-to-organize-eclipse-environment-on-multiple-monitors)